# USDA API Searching foods based on macronutrient content - Javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I'm utilizing the USDA API in a web app I'm creating. I need to be able to search the database for a specific amount of protein, carbs, and fats. The example they gave me shows me how to filter by the names (protein, carbs, and fats) but not the values. This is what I have that returns everything in the database, but I only want results that match specific values such as: 20g of protein, 40g of carbs, 10g of fat.

EDIT: I now realize I'm getting a JSON object back. The object has multiple fields and I just need to extract the information from the object instead of trying to filter the result.

This is the documentation:
https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/doc/index

Then the part about nutrient lists:
https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/doc/apilist/API-NUTRIENT-REPORT.md

Thanks in advance.

```js
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  async: false,
  url:"http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/?format=json&api_key=key&nutrients=205&nutrients=204&nutrients=203",
  success: function(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you include a link to the API documentation at the Question?

Comment: It's not a good idea to share you API key...

Comment: Ok I put the documentation in, sorry.... And yeah it's prob a good idea to take the key out... Thanks.